# Error Alpine Expression Error: Cannot read properties of undefined when deleting data from key/value pair in console

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I receive the following errors when using the `removeData` function in the code below.

> Alpine Expression Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
>
> Expression: "data[id].name"
>
> `<input x-model="data[id].name" type="text" name="name"></input>`

> Alpine Expression Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'text')
>
> Expression: "data[id].text"
>
> `<input x-model="data[id].text" type="text" name="text"></input>`

Everything appears to work correctly but the error message is generated in the console. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

```js
function handler() {
  return {
    data: {},
    getData() {
      console.log(this.data);
    },
    addData() {
      x = Object.keys(this.data);
      x = x.map(function(x) {
        return parseInt(x, 10);
      }).sort();
      n = x[x.length - 1];
      if (isNaN(n)) {
        n = 0;
      };
      this.data[n + 1] = {
        'name': '',
        'text': ''
      }
    },
    removeData(id) {
      delete this.data[id];
    },
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>

<div x-data="handler()">
  <button type="button" @click="getData()">ShowData</button>
  <button type="button" @click="addData()">AddData</button>
  <template x-for="[id, value] in Object.entries(data)" :key="id">
    <div :id="id">
      <input x-model="id" type="number">
      <input x-model="data[id].name" type="text" name="name">
      <input x-model="data[id].text" type="text" name="text">
      <button type="button" @click="removeData(id)">Remove</button>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Next time, please include the error messages in full and note which part of your script they refer to

Comment: @Phil Thank you for adding it. I will be sure to do so next time.

Answer (score 0):

If you correct the following, you will find the cause.

```
this.data[n + 1] = {
//+
        'name': `${n+1}taro`,
        'text': `${n+1}taro san shibakariheitta`
      }
    },

//+
  <pre x-text="JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

How about the following as a solution?

```
//+
      <input x-model="value.name" type="text" name="name">
      <input x-model="value.text" type="text" name="text">
```

Comment: I think this is interesting.
this is a vlookUp function, isn't it?      

<input x-model="id" type="number">
<input x-model="data[id].name" type="text" name="name">
<input x-model="data[id].text" type="text" name="text">